# How can I see this special case of tensor definition as a definition of vectors(quantities with both magnitude and direction)in $\mathbb R^3$?[Edited]

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, tensors

[image]

**Doubt:-**

What is the physical meaning of tensor? How can I see this special case of tensor definition as a definition of vectors(quantities with both magnitude and direction)in $\mathbb R^3$? Please help me. I could see $L_0(V)$ as a set of scalars. So, $k-\text{tensors on } V$ is a generalization of scalars. When $k=0$ tensors are scalars. How can I see vectors like this?

Comment: Why negative vote? Why is the question not eligible for an answer? Please help me to correct the question.

Comment: A $k$-tensor is essentially a matrix represented in $k$ dimensions, so a 'vector is a $1$-tensor and a matrix is a $2$- tensor. A confusing issue is that in physics people say tensor when they mean what a mathematician would call a tensor-valued function or a tensor field.

Comment: You mean  2-tensor means $Row 1-[f(e_1,e_1) f(e_1, e_2)], Row 2-[f(e_2,e_1) f(e_2, e_2)]$ like this?

Comment: How it is the generalisation of ordinary vectors?

Comment: the set of all tensors is also a vector space

Comment: yes. How is it related to Euclidean space? How it is related to Vectors(quantity having both magnitude and direction)?

Comment: Have you studied some basic linear algebra? It would really help. You should first know what a vector exactly is. Something with magnitude and direction is not a good definition.

Comment: yes! Vector spaces are the generalization of those collections of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. But in some sort of special casing, I should get like that. right? I might miss something from a linear algebra course. Can you fill the gap?@mathemather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0-tensors are constant functions, which we identify with scalars.

1-tensors are linear functions, which we identify with vectors. This identification amounts to selecting an inner product: we identify the vector $x$ with the function $y \mapsto \langle x,y \rangle$.

2-tensors are bilinear functions, which we identify with matrices. This identification also amounts to selecting an inner product: we identify the matrix $A$ with the function $(x,y) \mapsto \langle x,Ay \rangle$.

Things become a bit foreign when we go to $k$-tensors with $k>2$. One way to think about it is that a $k$-tensor takes a vector and gives back a $(k-1)$-tensor. Thus for instance a $3$-tensor takes a vector and gives back a matrix.

Comment: How do you guarantee that $V$ is Inner product space?

Comment: You don't, but selecting an inner product provides such an identification. Without selecting an inner product, tensors remain abstract linear functions.

Comment: Now i have one more doubt, stress tensors are actually bilinear. Right?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor

Comment: That is correct, though as I mentioned physicists often say tensor when they mean tensor field.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ian